# PYTHON: -bash: /usr/bin/yum: /usr/bin/python: intérprete erróneo: No existe el fichero o el directorio

Tags: python, python-2.7

Por defecto en Centos tenia Python 2.6, asi que decidí instalar un version mas reciente 2.7.12, mas antes ya había instalado los entornos virtuales(VIRTUALENV y VIRTUALWRAPPER) y resulta que ahora no puedo ni crear un entorno virtual ni ejecutar comandos de linux, me lanza estos errores que detallo:

por ejemplo intento actualizar :

```
root@vps3 [~]# yum update
```

me arroja :

```
-bash: /usr/bin/yum: /usr/bin/python: intérprete erróneo: No existe el fichero o el directorio
```

hasta he reiniciado mi server y accedo por SSH me arroja este mensaje

```
    /usr/local/bin/python: No module named virtualenvwrapper
virtualenvwrapper.sh: There was a problem running the initialization hooks. 

If Python could not import the module virtualenvwrapper.hook_loader,
check that virtualenvwrapper has been installed for
VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_PYTHON=/usr/local/bin/python and that PATH is
set properly.
```

cuando intento crear un entorno virtual con `root@vps3 [~]# mkvirtualenv djangoprueba`

arroja este error:

```
-bash: /usr/bin/virtualenv: /usr/bin/python: intérprete erróneo: No existe el fichero o el directorio
```

Finalmente lo he eliminado la antigua version de PYTHON por completo al parecer, así esta mi actual instalación:

```
root@vps3 [~]# type -a python

python is /usr/local/bin/python
python is /usr/local/bin/python
python is /usr/local/bin/python
python is /usr/local/bin/python
```

ubicando python

```
root@vps3 [~]# which python
/usr/local/bin/python
```

cuando acceso en consola me arroja por defecto 2.7.12:

```
root@vps3 [~]# python
Python 2.7.12 (default, Jul  3 2017, 04:21:53) 
[GCC 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-18)] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>
```

en el `cd /usr/bin/python`,  veo estos archivos:

```
python            python2           python2.6         python2.6-config  python-config
```

y en `root@vps3 [~]# cd /usr/local/bin/python` veo estos archivos:

```
python            python2           python2.7         python2.7-config  python2-config    python-config
```

La verdad estoy confundido, no sé que es lo esta fallando, dudo que falta un enlace por defecto a Python de python2.7.12? o que se puede hacer para solucionar, gracias por su ayuda

Comment: No se si será una solución pero intenta crear un link simbólico `ln -s /usr/local/bin/python /usr/bin/python` o abre cada script y cambia el intérprete a usar en la primera línea: por ejemplo para yum abres `usr/bin/yum` y cambia `#!/usr/bin/python` por `#!/usr/local/bin/python`

Comment: Si lo he generado el enlace simbólico y me dice que ya existe el archivo, en que Script lo puedo reemplazar #!/usr/local/bin/python  ? Gracias

Comment: En teoria con el enlace simbólico deberia llamar a tu intérprete en local sin hacer nada más. Reamplazar la directiva es otra alternativa diferente, en aquellos script que usen usr/bin/python como intérprete la cambias para que usen #!/usr/local/bin/python. Para hacerlo así tienes que hacer esto en todos los scripts con problemas, por eso crear el enlace simbólico es más rápido. Claro que para que esto funcione los scripts tienen que ser compatibles con Python 2.7 y no se si es así. ¿Es extraño que te eliminara el 2.6, puedes llamarlo manualmente con `$ /usr/bin/python`?

Comment: cuando llamo asi: `$ /usr/bin/python`  me arroja
`´-bash: /usr/bin/python:  No existe el fichero o el directorio `
´

Comment: Gracias @FJSevilla me ayudo mucho tu aporte abajo dejo la solución

Answer (score 3):

Lo he solucionado de la siguiente manera:

primero lo he eliminado el enlace simbólico que he generado

```
[~]# rm /usr/bin/python
```

algo asi sale

```
/usr/local/bin/python2.7-config
/usr/local/bin/python2.7
/usr/bin/python2.6
/usr/bin/python2.6-config
/root/.virtualenvs/django1.10.5/bin/python2
/opt/rh/python27/root/usr/bin/python2.7-config
/opt/rh/python27/root/usr/bin/python2.7
```

ahora voy a averiguar el camino a encontrar YUM así:

```
cat `which yum` | head -1
```

me sale asi

```
#!/usr/bin/python
```

ahora creamos de nuevo el enlace simbólico con lo que tenia originalmente python 2.6 así:

```
ln -s /usr/bin/python2.6 /usr/bin/python
```

y todo a funcionado, que milagro.

Comment: Me alegra que al final lo solucionaras. Todo tiene solución, yo he cometido muchas burradas a lo largo de mi vida *nix, lo que incluye borrar por error todos los kernel del sistema... :(, pero nunca he tenido que reinstalar el SO  por estos experimentos catastróficos (ese es el camino fácil y no aprendes nada) XD. Gracias por compartir, puede ser de gran ayuda a otros con tu problema.  Saludos y +1.